# How to hide one section of the page and show the other section when a heading is clicked? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made this example up in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yt88bsnf/1/

One section has a display of none, and the other is shown. What I am trying to accomplish is when the one of the h2 element is clicked, that section below becomes shown (unless it is already shown, then it would stay shown), and the other h2 element display changes to none (unless it already has a display of none).

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <h2>Section One</h2>
    <h2>Section Two</h2>
</div>

<div id="section_one">
    This is Section One
</div>

<div id="section_two">
    This is Section Two
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
    overflow:hidden;
}

#container h2{
    float:left;
    margin-right:30px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#section_two{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/yt88bsnf/3/)

You can use jquery `show()` and `hide()`. For more information see [W3Scools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp)

And for the docs see here

- [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)
- [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

**JS**

```
$("#header1").click(function () {

    $("#section_one").show();
    $("#section_two").hide();
});
$("#header2").click(function () {

    $("#section_two").show();
    $("#section_one").hide();

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
     <h2 id="header1">Section One</h2>

     <h2 id="header2">Section Two</h2>

</div>
<div id="section_one">This is Section One</div>
<div id="section_two">This is Section Two</div>
```

I've added each `h2` an id (header1 and header2) and used that id to show and hide the divs respectively..Please Try it..

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery you can use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button1').on('click', function() {
        $('#section_one').show();
        $('#section_two').hide();
    });

    $('#button2').on('click', function() {
        $('#section_one').hide();
        $('#section_two').show();
    });    
});
```

i added two id's to the h2's to reference them for the click event.

if you are using more than two sections you might want to use a loop to iterate through them and change their visibility. in that case you could also use the h2's index to check which section should be shown.

see [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yt88bsnf/2/)

Answer (score 0):

## [JS Fiddle Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yt88bsnf/4/)

An easy way to do it would be to wrap these in their individual parents like:

```
<div class="parent">
    <h1>Section One</h1>
    <p>Section One</p>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <h1>Section Two</h1>
    <p style="visibility: hidden;">Section Two</p>
</div>
```

This way you can add multiple sections in your dom and this jQuery would be enough:

```
$(".parent").children("h1").click(function(){
    $(".parent").children("p").css("visibility", "hidden");
    $(this).siblings("p").css("visibility", "visible");
});
```

Feel free to ask any questions in comments.

Answer (score 0):

The following jquery code allows you to hide show the div's irrespective of the number of div's and also do not require additional id's to be created.

```
$("#container").on('click','h2',function(){//click on any h2 in container
     //hide all div's having section id starting with section_
   $("div[id^='section_']").hide();
    //show the div which has index position equal to the clicked h2 
  $($("div[id^='section_']")[$(this).index()]).show(); 
});
```

See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3pmakwh4/